# Solving non-linear recurrence for solving infinite ladder circuit

Tags: recurrence-relations, mathematical-physics

I am trying to solve an infinite ladder circuit. Let $\gamma_n$ denote the equivalent capacitance in the $n$th step. I arrived at the following recurrence relation linking $\gamma_{n-1}$ and $\gamma_n$. I am not sure how to get the equivalent capacitance from the recurrence relation so obtained.

> $$\gamma_{n-1}=\frac{(\gamma _n+2^{n-1}\alpha)2^{n-2}\alpha}{\gamma_n+3\cdot2^{n-2}\alpha}$$

How to solve this recurrence relation? Since $n\to \infty$, $\gamma_{n-1}=\gamma_{n}$ but that would require putting in $n\to \infty$ into the entire expression, which seems to be indicating $\lim \gamma_n \to \infty$ and that might be true. So only taking the limit does not give the equivalent capacitance. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does $\gamma_n$ need to stay positive forever? I see a possibility that the solution for some initial data is not positive forever, namely if $\gamma_0$ is huge. This is simply because $f(x)=\frac{(x+\alpha/2)\alpha/4}{x+3\alpha/4}$ isn't surjective on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Ian Since this is representing capacitance, $\gamma_n$ should be positive by definition.

Comment: So where is your boundary condition then? Is $\gamma_0$ given, or what? And if $\gamma_0$ is given, what ensures it is in the necessary range to have $\gamma_1>0$?

Comment: @Ian The value of $\gamma_0$ is not known, because that is what the equivalent capacitance would be and that is the unknown in the problem.

Comment: So is $\gamma_\infty$ given then? Or some large $n$ asymptotic for $\gamma_n$. At present the problem seems ill-posed.

Comment: The trick is to notice that if you cut off one step, you get an identical infinite ladder (which has the same capacitance).

Comment: @KeithMcClary I know that method, I was trying to solve using recurrence and getting a general answer for $n$ step ladder first.

Comment: The problem though is that you need some boundary condition. In the infinite ladder you can use the requirement of self-similarity, which tells you what the effective capacitance would have to be if you removed one capacitor from the ladder, and then you require this to be the same as what you started with.

Comment: (Cont.) In a finite structure you can't do this anymore, so you have to do something else, including coming up with some boundary condition. And it's not necessarily going to be easy to find the solution to the finite problem, which will have some "finite size effect" that isn't resolved in the infinite solution. To see that finite size effect you'd probably need to do numerics because I don't think there is likely to be a closed form solution to, say, $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+2},x_1=1$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for clarifying the case with $n$ step ladder of capacitors. Let's say we had some initial condition, how would we then solve this recurrence? Is there an algorithm?

Comment: Numerically you can just keep plugging in values (once you have written $\gamma_n$ in terms of $\gamma_{n-1}$ anyway, which you can do algebraically here). In terms of a closed form I don't know how to get one.

Comment: Actually I do know how to get one, though it is a bit silly. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Also I don't really know where all these exponentials came from if you're trying to deal with a capacitor ladder, maybe the picture of the capacitor ladder that you have in mind is different from the usual one. If so then let me know so I can fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you basically want to do is to solve the recurrence $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+2},x_1=a$ where $a$ is given. If $a$ is rational, then $x_n$ will always be rational say of the form $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ so $x_{n+1}=\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{\frac{p_n}{q_n}+1}{\frac{p_n}{q_n}+2}=\frac{p_n+q_n}{p_n+2q_n}$. (Also note that if $p_n,q_n$ were coprime then the same is true of $p_n+q_n$ and $p_n+2q_n$.)

Thus the numerator and denominator satisfy the matrix recursion $\begin{bmatrix} p_{n+1} \\ q_{n+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p_n \\ q_n \end{bmatrix}$. This matrix recurrence can be solved explicitly by diagonalization, you wind up with

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \left ( \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right )^n & 0 \\ 0 & \left ( \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right )^n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} & \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10} \\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} & \frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10} \end{bmatrix}.$$

and $\begin{bmatrix} p_{n+1} \\ q_{n+1} \end{bmatrix}$ is that thing times $\begin{bmatrix} p_1 \\ q_1 \end{bmatrix}$. You can see that for large $n$ everything concentrates onto the second eigenvector so you end up with $p_n/q_n \to \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ regardless of the (rational) initial data. You can write an explicit closed form for the ratio from here if you want.